# Can an Event Handler return a value?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to write a class that its constructor takes as argument a String ( which is an image in my directory ie: jpg ) and load the corresponding image via a loader object in memory. I also provide function getBitmapFromLoader() to get the bitmap of the loader in order to use it from another class.

```
public class LoadImage extends Loader
{
    private var bitmap:Bitmap;
    private var ldr:Loader;

    public function LoadImage(nameURL:String):void
    {
        trace("LoadImage constructor");
        ldr = new Loader();
        ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorEventHandler);
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(nameURL);
        ldr.load(request);
    }

    /* methods */
    public function getBitmapFromLoader():Bitmap
    {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public function toSprite():Sprite
    {
        trace("toSprite method");
        var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
        sprite.addChild(bitmap);
        return sprite;
    }

    public function toMovieClip():MovieClip
    {
        trace("toMovieClip method");
        var mvc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        mvc.addChild(bitmap);
        return mvc;
    }

    private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        trace("completeHandler " + event.currentTarget);
        bitmap = new Bitmap();
        bitmap = Bitmap(event.currentTarget.content);
    }

    private function ioErrorEventHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        trace("ioErrorEventHandler " + event.currentTarget);
        trace("error on loading image: " + event.currentTarget.url);
        bitmap = null;
    }
}
}
```

but it does not work.
 This is what flash outputs:

`Main constructor
LoadImage constructor
toSprite method
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
    at loader::LoadImage/toSprite()
    at Main()
completeHandler [object LoaderInfo]`

This is how i use it from a main class:

`package
{
    import loader.*;`

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    /* properties */

    /* constructor */
    public function Main():void
    {
        trace("Main constructor");
        var imgLdr:LoadImage = new LoadImage("smile_bg.jpg");
        var spr1:Sprite = imgLdr.toSprite();
        //this.width = spr1.width;
        //this.height = spr1.height;
        this.addChild(spr1);
    }

    /* methods */

}
```

}

Comment: you need to be a bit more specific than "does not work", also, go back and mark the answers to your past questions as accepted!

Comment: +1 on marking past answers as accepted. You'll have much better responses if you use the system the way it's intended.

Comment: as a side note, it seems to me that you class LoadImage does not need to extend Loader or at least you are not taking any advantages of the parent class in your code...

Comment: @goliatone: i think you're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a Loader is itself a DisplayObject - so you could just addChild(event.currentTarget) and it'll show up just fine. It extends DisplayObjectContainer just like Sprite does.

If you literally need a Bitmap, then you can do something like:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(event.currentTarget.width, event.currentTarget.height);
bmd.draw(event.currentTarget);
bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
```

And do it that way. You might have to tweak that a bit I'm going from memory.

If you're ever having issues with the Display API, this is a very good chart to summarize what lives where and how the various display object children are connected: http://accad.osu.edu/~pgerstma/class/pca/resources/as3API/AS3API-flash.display.png

Comment: thanks, actually when i changed the argument in addChild mathod it worked. But my basic need is to get the BitmapData of this loader object but from another class. So i think i cannot use the code you propose about the bitmapData. Of course now i can get it through the sprite reference i created, but can i get it another way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need exactly, but if it helps: anything that extends DisplayObject is drawable by BitmapData. That means that you can convert it directly into a BitmapData object by creating your bitmapData instance and saying "bmd.draw(targetDisplayObject)" - then you have a BitmapData object that contains the pixel data for whatever you're drawing. If this helps, please accept my answer as Hooray pointed out in the comments above. You'll get better help from the community if you accept answers. Cheers!

Comment: Basically, i have a class that loads the image via a Loader. And another class that will manipulate the data of its bitmapData. So, i will use the first class to load various images, and the second class to manipulate their bitmapdata data. So i have to reference to their bitmapdata somehow from an external class not the one that i use to load the images. And basically i ask what is the most appropriate way to transfer this information from the LoadImage class to lets say a Main class.

Comment: I guess you could create a custom event. Once you have your image loaded in your loader class, and once you've stripped out the bitmap data you need to pass over, do something like this:

var imageLoadedEvent:MyCustomImageEvent = new MyCustomImageEvent("MY_EVENT");
imageLoadedEvent.bitmapData = myBitmapData;
dispatchEvent(imageLoadedEvent);

Then in your main class, add a listener:

loaderClass.addEventListener("MY_EVENT", handler);

function handler(e:MyCustomImageEvent):void {
imageProcessorClass.process(e.bitmapData);
}

Does that make sense?